# How not to output a sequence with `TimeDistributed` layer in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am currently work on LSTM with Keras and I have a question about `TimeDistributed` layer.

Let's say that I have a  `TimeDistributed` layer which takes as input something like `(batch_size,timesteps,num_features1)`. It will output something like`(batch_size,timesteps,num_features2)`.

I would like instead to output something like `(batch_size,num_features2)`. Is it possible ?

It would be to stack a LSTM layer with `return_sequence = True` to a dense layer (using `TimeDistributed` layer) and then to go back to "classical" dense layer that accept input like `(batch_size,nb_features)`.

Thanks in advance !

Benoit

Comment: This means that you want to squash a time dimension - how do you want to do this? The most popular methods are either `global pooling` wrt. to time or taking a last output.

Comment: The idea could be that instead of returning`(batch_size,timesteps,num_features)`, I could return something like `(batch_size,timesteps)`. I will lokk at `global pooling`, thanks.

Comment: Regarding the title of your question, the thing is, TimeDistributed is made to be applied and preserve the time dimension, so it will return the time sequence anyway. The only thing you can influence with TimeDistributed is the number of features per time step. You can reduce it to one feature by applying a layer which has dimension 1 for its output and then flatten. But you cant go from (None, timesteps, features) to (None, feat_1, feat-2). Im still not sure i get your question

Comment: @NassimBen I think he wants to get to (None, Timesteps, 1) => (None, Timesteps). Maybe this can be done by adding all the features for each time dimension. For example, if the TimeDistributed layer gives (None, Timesteps, 100) as output, so for each timestep the 100-dimensional vector should be summed up to give a single value. Maybe this can work but I am not sure of how can we implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to exactly understand what you want so I will put here a network that I think is what you want. If it isn't, please edit your question with a draft of the network you want and the shapes at each steps. 
It would be also easier to know what you want to achieve with this network.

```
model = sequential()
# shape = (None,timesteps, num_feat1)
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(num_feat2))
# shape = (None,timesteps, num_feat2)
model.add(LSTM(1, return_sequence=True))
# shape = (None, timesteps, 1)
model.add(Flatten())
# shape = (None, timesteps)
model.add(Dense(num_outputs_desired))
# shape = (None, outputs)
```

is that what  you want? This (1) transforms the initial features equally on each timestep with a dense layer time distributed, (2) processes the sequence with an lstm, returning 1 value at each step, (3) use a dense layer to transform the sequence of values to a desired output (which I don't know how it should be, what is the aim of your model?).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted ! Thanks Nassim. I did not know `model.add(Flatten())`

Comment: Welcome :) glad it helped